# Cannot import python class from another directory

Tags: python

Here i have following directory structure,

```
src/models/UserModel.py
src/resources/UserResources.py
```

and `UserModel.py` contains

```
from datetime import datetime
from run import db
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256 as sha256
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from flask import jsonify


class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id            = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username      = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True, nullable = False)
    password      = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable = False)
    user_role     = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable = False)
    access_token  = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True, nullable = True)
    refresh_token = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True, nullable = True)

    def save_to_db(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

and `UserResources.py` file imports `UserModel` like this `from models import UserModel`

even though the models directory having the `__init__.py` file, it raises the following error `ImportError: cannot import name 'UserModel' from 'models'`

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: have you tried `from src.models import UserModel`

Comment: yeah but it also gives the same error

Comment: How about `from ..models import UserModel`

Comment: @whydoubt then `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: You must have `src` on your Python path. Easiest to set the environmental variable [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) to include `src` on Linux/Mac `export PYTHONPATH=path/to/src` on Windows use `set PYTHONPATH=path\to\src`.

Comment: @MarkMikofski should where can i set PYTHONPATH ? is it on system variables or inside the project directory ?

Comment: Is `UserResources` a script, or do you intend to import it from somewhere else? By default Python assumes that scripts are at top level, not in modules, so if you're just running `python UserResources.py` it will not find the package correctly. Instead, try `python -m resources.UserResources` from the `src` folder and it should work.

Comment: @Blckknght nope `UserResources` is a class

Comment: I think there's a confusion of terminology here. You've described a module `UserResources.py`. It may *contain* a class, but it is also a module, which you appear to be running as a script leading to your errors. Python doesn't require every class to be in it's own file like Java does. So one possible solution to your problem is to move your class elsewhere, if it helps with the import issues you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
from src.models.UserModel import UserModel
```

Comment: got it Thanks :-)